# Can the helium from a gas bottle lift the bottle?

Tags: gravity, experimental-physics, gas

Does a gas bottle full of helium contain so much helium that, if the helium can expand into a baloon, can lift the empty gas bottle?

And input on this question highly appreciated...

Comment: Yes and no. It depends on the capacity of the tank and the max rated tank pressure. This would be an interesting problem to solve.

Comment: A thinner tank wall means less mass however you can't pressurize as much to get a larger capacity.

Comment: I was thinking of a kind of standard bottle used to fill up, like, birthday balloons. But any other bottle (or big tank) would be nice to have (if someone has the numbers...)

Comment: There are standard cylinders and custom,  and many sizes, pressures. I suspect there might be an 'optimum' size relative to lift/size if custom design were considered

Comment: That would be interesting if helium in a helium canister would lift the canister.  You know the mass of the helium and from that get volume at atmospheric temp.  From there buoyancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical bottle volume 50 L, pressure 200 atm (values used in scuba diving). This means that the expanded helium would have a volume of 10,000 liters, providing about 10 kg of lift. That is not enough to lift a typical scuba tank (about 15 kg).

So I would say "no", for a long thin tank (shaped like a scuba tank). It would be possible to conceive of a helium tank that *could* do this. Obviously, a lower pressure tank with larger diameter would have a more favorable ratio of mass to volume: if you say that the wall thickness scales with pressure times diameter (same amount of material supporting same amount of pressure), but the "potential lifting capacity" scales with pressure times diameter squared (expanded volume), then you can see that a larger diameter tank could do it.

Update - I found [specifications of a helium "K type" cylinder](http://www.praxairdirect.com/PXItemDisplay%3FcatalogId%3D10051%26parent_category_rn%3D11504%26top_category%3D11501%26categoryId%3D11537%26langId%3D-1%26storeId%3D10152%26itemID%3D66993). They cite a pressure of 2200 psi, volume of 217 cu ft. That translates to 150 atm, 6145 liters (expanded... or 40 liters unexpanded). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_cylinder) the K type cylinder has a mass of 110 lbs or about 50 kg. It won't fly...

Comment: It won't so much fly as plummet... (Sorry, feeling Monty-Pythonish today).

Comment: @JonCuster I recommend nailing it down then.